# sbt-native-packager fails with dpkg-deb error

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am getting an error when trying to deploy sbt project using the sbt-native-packager.
I have used the packager for years, but in previous projects it is an older version.

I am using version 1.9.7, with sbt 1.9.8 (Oracle Corporation Java 17.0.10).
The command is: `Debian / packageBin`

I get the following error:

```
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] done compiling
[info] Building debian package with native implementation
[error] dpkg-deb: error: --build takes at most two arguments
[error] Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
[error] Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages.
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Debian / packageBin for the full output
[error] (Debian / packageBin) Failure packaging debian file.  Exit code: 2
[error] Total time: 26 s, completed 19 Feb 2024, 15:19:37
```

Staging goes fine, so it has to do with the final assembly, but I cannot find a way to get debug information on the command and what the arguments that are passed to --build and why.

Any help is really appreciated as I am stuck for a long time now on this last step of deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when adding the required information for the Debian Package Build I put in the name with a space (thinking it was the display name). This caused a space in the build path and hence it complains about two arguments.